# Java - Is Set.contains() broken on OpenJDK 6?

Tags: java, set, equals, contains

I've come across a really strange problem. I have written a simple `Deck` class which represents a standard 52 card deck of playing cards. The class has a method `missingCards()` which returns the set of all cards which have been drawn from the deck. If I try and compare two identical sets of missing cards using `.equals()` I'm told they are different, and if I check to see if a set contains an element that I know is there using `.contains()` I am returned `false`.

Here is my test code:

```
    public void testMissingCards() 
{
    Deck deck = new Deck(true);
    Set<Card> drawnCards = new HashSet<Card>();
    drawnCards.add(deck.draw());
    drawnCards.add(deck.draw());
    drawnCards.add(deck.draw());
    Set<Card> missingCards = deck.missingCards();
    System.out.println(drawnCards);
    System.out.println(missingCards);
    Card c1 = null;
    for (Card c : drawnCards){
        c1 = c;
    }
    System.out.println("C1 is "+c1);
    for (Card c : missingCards){
        System.out.println("C is "+c);
        System.out.println("Does c1.equal(c) "+c1.equals(c));
        System.out.println("Does c.equal(c1) "+c.equals(c1));
    }
    System.out.println("Is c1 in missingCards "+missingCards.contains(c1));
    assertEquals("Deck confirm missing cards",drawnCards,missingCards);
}
```

(Edit: Just for clarity I added the two loops after I noticed the test failing. The first loop pulls out a card from drawnCards and then this card is checked against every card in missingCards  - it always matches one, so that card must be contained in missingCards. However, missingCards.contains() fails)

And here is an example of it's output:

```
[5C, 2C, 2H]
[2C, 5C, 2H]
C1 is 2H
C is 2C
Does c1.equal(c) false
Does c.equal(c1) false
C is 5C
Does c1.equal(c) false
Does c.equal(c1) false
C is 2H
Does c1.equal(c) true
Does c.equal(c1) true
Is c1 in missingCards false
```

I am completely sure that the implementation of .equals on my card class is correct and, as you can see from the output it does work!

What is going on here?

Cheers,

Pete

Comment: There's a curly brace out of place, so youre looping through all of the cards once, then keeping the last one only in c1, and checking it once.

Comment: That was intentional, I was extremely confused so I wrote some extremely rough and ready tests.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You forgot to implement [hashCode()](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode()) in a way consistent to [equals()](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) :)
(I.e., equal objects must return the same hash code).

Comment: Almost certainly true. Poster should really have posted Card.java for us to be sure.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I hadn't implemented hashCode(). Do you have any tips on how I can best implemented hashCode (a card has a the fields face and suit which are both integers)?

Comment: Eclipse will auto generate a reasonable hashCode and equals at the same time in 1 click.

Comment: @Peter, Effective Java 2nd version, Item 9, contains a whole load of tips. Some shortcuts include Arrays.hashCode() (http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html?is-external=true#hashCode(java.lang.Object[])) and Objects.hashCode() (of Guava) (http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Objects.html#hashCode(java.lang.Object...))

Hmm, am I missing a better way to paste links in comments?

Answer (score 8):

> Java - Is Set.contains() broken on OpenJDK 6?

No it is not.

The first rule of debugging Java is that 99.9% of the time it is *your* code that is broken, and not the Java standard libraries.

Answer (score 3):

What about hashCode?  You should always override the two together, according to Joshua Bloch's "Effective Java" [chapter 3](http://java.sun.com/developer/Books/effectivejava/Chapter3.pdf).

Post your Card class.  It'll be easy to spot then.

Comment: Why on earth was this downvoted?  It's the same answer as the one that was accepted.

Answer (score 2):

Please post the code for the `Deck` class -- at least the `equals(Object)` and the `hashCode()` methods.

My first guess is that you only implemented `equals()`, but not `hashCode()`. If that's the case, read the documentation of the `java.lang.Object` class.